# Jackson JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)

Tags: json, circular-reference, jackson-databind

I have a problem converting the object into its equivalent JSON.

Following is my class structure:

```
public class Record {
    private byte[] header;
    private String mti;
    private String bitmap;
    private int fieldNumber;
    private String data;
    private String name;
    private String recordType;
    private List<Record> subRecords;
    private Field recordSchema;
    private List<PDSRecord> pdsRecords;
}
```

In my case, a record can have multiple sub-records and then each sub-record can further have multiple sub-records. Therefore, I came up with this schema to store the records.

The problem I'm facing is due to the Circular Reference of `List<Record>` inside `Record` class.

Is there anyway Jackson could convert this object? Also, I would need the complete information of all the sub-records.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a cycle between `record` and `subRecords`. Use `@JsonIgnore` to break it

Comment: Using `@JsonIgnore` doesn't print the values of the `subRecords`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve it. For this, I had to generate a unique Id for every object that is created and mark the class with:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id")
```

So, the complete class looks like this:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Data // Lombok 
public class Record {
    private String id;
    private byte[] header;
    private String mti;
    private String bitmap;
    private int fieldNumber;
    private String data;
    private String name;
    private String recordType;
    @ToString.Exclude // Lombok
    private List<Record> subRecords;
    private Field recordSchema;
    private List<PDSRecord> pdsRecords;

    public Record()
    {
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

You can try the below code. I hope this solves your problem.

```
    try{
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
        String value = mapper.writeValueAsString(r3);
        System.out.println(value);
    }catch(IOException a){
        a.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Output:`{
  "header": "UEFOS0FK",
  "mti": "Data",
  "bitmap": "Name",
  "fieldNumber": 5,
  "data": "data",
  "name": "name",
  "recordType": "Data",
  "subRecords": [
    {
      "header": "UEFOS0FK",
      "mti": "Data",
      "bitmap": "Name",
      "fieldNumber": 5,
      "data": "data",
      "name": "name",
      "recordType": "Data",
      "subRecords": [
        {
          "header": "UEFOS0FK",
          "mti": "Data",
          "bitmap": "Name",
          "fieldNumber": 5,
          "data": "data",
          "name": "name",
          "recordType": "Data",
          "subRecords": null,
          "recordSchema": "Record schema",
          "pdsRecords": []
        }
      ],
      "recordSchema": "Record schema",
      "pdsRecords": []
    }
  ],
  "recordSchema": "Record schema",
  "pdsRecords": []
}`

Comment: Cool, I will try it and let you know.

Comment: Nope... it didn't worked for me.  I had to define the unique ID for every object and mark it with `@JsonIdentityInfo`.

Comment: Please be specific about your question. Your question was no where related what you have answered. Hence marking it down

Comment: I was getting infinite recursion exception and I asked for the solution. And the solution is what I found afterwards. And would you like to explain why your code solves the problem that I mentioned.